# Ruby on Cygwin produces no output at all?

Tags: ruby, cygwin, rake

The title says it all; my ruby installation on cygwin is no longer producing any output for any ruby-related command.  As far as I know I have done nothing with my installation since the last time I used ruby, and it most certainly was functioning at full capacity when I last used it.  I use the Ceedling rake-based tool for embedded unit tests, and it ran my full suite of tests just fine before...

As far as I can tell it is installed correctly:

```
~ $ ruby -v
~ $ rake test:all
~ $ irb
~ $ gem blah
~ $ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
~ $ which rake
/usr/bin/rake
~ $ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolft01 Domain Users 10259 Jun 27  2016 /usr/bin/ruby
~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/rake
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolft01 Domain Users 485 May 20  2015 /usr/bin/rake
~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/irb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolft01 Domain Users 186 Jun 27  2016 /usr/bin/irb
~ $ cygcheck -c ruby
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
ruby                 2.2.5-1        OK
~ $ time ruby -v

real    0m0.868s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.031s
```

As you can tell, all ruby -related programs produce no output and don't care what their arguments are.  Executables are located where which thinks they are, and none of them have been messed with for some time.  I have done a restart and even a re-install of ruby from the cygwin installer and still no output.  I have attempted to run the programs from their "true" location in /bin and there's no change (/bin is mounted at /usr/bin).

As much as I've used and configure it, I am fairly ignorant of cygwin's internals.  Is there anything obvious going on here that I am missing?  None of my other programs have this problem.  I would add that, when it was working, ruby was VERY slow when running anything to do with gems.  A rake test:all would take maybe 10+ seconds before I would see output.  I am on an i5 (Lenovo T450), but even on my personal Surfacebook it would take a second or two to start truly running.  I have yet to check that the Surfacebook cygwin environment has this new ruby problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

Unfortunately I think I've found the issue, and it jives with the time-frame when ruby suddenly stopped working.  I've spent an hour or two running through the installer, updating the installer to the latest version, installing an older version of ruby, and all to no avail.  I didn't originally think to run an strace since there was no output at all from the program (and it seemed like a cygwin problem), but figured I might try in case it was actually doing something, and here's what I've found:

```
~ $ strace ruby -v
--- Process 17756 created
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00000000778F0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00000000777D0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 000007FEFD6A0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\tmumh\20019\AddOn\6.80.0.1007\TmUmEvt64.dll at 000007FEFC670000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\psapi.dll at 0000000077AB0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll at 000007FEFF270000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 000007FEFF480000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00000000776D0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lpk.dll at 000007FEFDF90000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\usp10.dll at 000007FEFDAA0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 000007FEFFB60000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 000007FEFE120000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 000007FEFF350000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 000007FEFDE60000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\tmumh\20019\TmMon\1.6.0.1175\tmmon64.dll at 0000000075280000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\cygwin64\bin\cygruby220.dll at 00000003EA660000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\cygwin64\bin\cygcrypt-0.dll at 00000003F8490000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll at 0000000180040000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\cygwin64\bin\cyggmp-10.dll at 00000003F5A90000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\cygwin64\bin\cygssp-0.dll at 00000003EA110000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 000007FEFE2D0000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\msctf.dll at 000007FEFF370000
--- Process 17756 thread 12568 created
--- Process 17756 thread 13660 created
--- Process 17756 thread 7880 created
    1       1 [main] ruby (17756) **********************************************
   94      95 [main] ruby (17756) Program name: C:\cygwin64\bin\ruby.exe (windows pid 17756)
   14     109 [main] ruby (17756) OS version:   Windows NT-6.1
   10     119 [main] ruby (17756) **********************************************
   61     180 [main] ruby (17756) sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x0, 0x1802E4BB0)
 3273    3453 [main] ruby 17756 open_shared: name shared.5, n 5, shared 0x180030000 (wanted 0x180030000), h 0xD4, *m 6
   69    3522 [main] ruby 17756 user_heap_info::init: heap base 0x600000000, heap top 0x600000000, heap size 0x20000000 (536870912)
   62    3584 [main] ruby 17756 open_shared: name S-1-5-21-410091219-1949443337-794563710-80728.1, n 1, shared 0x180020000 (wanted 0x180020000), h 0xD0, *m 6
   23    3607 [main] ruby 17756 user_info::create: opening user shared for 'S-1-5-21-410091219-1949443337-794563710-80728' at 0x180020000
   15    3622 [main] ruby 17756 user_info::create: user shared version AB1FCCE8
  423    4045 [main] ruby 17756 fhandler_pipe::create: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-e022582115c10879-17756-sigwait, size 11440, mode PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
  101    4146 [main] ruby 17756 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe read handle 0xE8
   60    4206 [main] ruby 17756 fhandler_pipe::create: CreateFile: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-e022582115c10879-17756-sigwait
   46    4252 [main] ruby 17756 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe write handle 0xEC
   27    4279 [main] ruby 17756 dll_crt0_0: finished dll_crt0_0 initialization
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Avecto\Privilege Guard Client\PGHook.dll at 000007FEFD450000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll at 000007FEFD390000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll at 000007FEFD340000
--- Process 17756 loaded \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll at 000007FEFD330000
--- Process 17756 thread 11088 created
--- Process 17756, exception c0000005 at 0000000180127C9A
...
(A crap ton more of the same exception, at least 500 or so)
...
--- Process 17756 thread 20322 exited with status 0xc0000005
--- Process 17756 thread 12568 exited with status 0xc0000005
--- Process 17756 exited with status 0xc0000005
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, it loads the DLLs just fine and begins execution of Ruby, but then this Avecto Privilege Guard Client's dll and a few cryptography-related dlls get loaded.  This makes me think that it is this new Avecto security product that the company is using, but I have some doubts.  For one, I can run strace on vim and get a similar output, but vim works just fine.  Python works fine, but strace fails on it (error creating process python, (error 2)).

So the security system may be the culprit, but in a way that only seems to affect Ruby.  I know that with whatever we were using before Ruby was incredibly slow, especially when using gems (on the order of 10-20 seconds to begin a rake test:blah), so it seems like Ruby is more heavily affected by security products.  I am not familiar with how reliable strace is on cygwin, so if these segfaults in strace are unusual that would be another finger to point at Avecto.

We have moved to using this Avecto product as well as Bitlocker since I last used ruby, so it would make sense that one of these products is the problem.  I won't put this as an answer until I can get some sort of verification, though (which will be difficult, as I cannot disable either product).  Looks like I might be moving to a VM with some type of offline repository bridge (just found https://sourceforge.net/projects/camicricube/).

Comment: You are likely missing a shared lib. try `cygcheck /usr/bin/ruby.exe` to indentify it

Comment: @matzeri I ran that command and all of the dlls listed are present on my system.  I'm not too familiar with the cygcheck command, so if the output is pertinent (other than checking that all files are on my system) I can put it in my question.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @matzeri I just completed the process of uninstalling, verifying that it was uninstalled, and then reinstalling ruby and all related packages.  Nothing has changed, so it's definitely not an install-related problem.  Unless there is an issue with the 2.2.5-1 version (or my cygwin installer, which works for other packages just fine).

Comment: If the shared lib are present then is it a old version problem, Run `strace /usr/bin/ruby.exe -v` to find which shared lib is wrong.

Comment: @matzeri See the edit to my question.  I think the problem is with my company's new use of Avecto Defendpoint.  You can see it and several crypto libraries being loaded before the exception.